# Angular 1.5.x Component Router Resolve

Tags: angularjs

I have been looking at the Angular 1.5.x ComponentRouter and am trying to find a way to mimic the uiRouter resolve functionality. I have tried `$routerOnActivate` but it does not block the route from changing. Does anyone have the answer or a good reference to this functionality. In the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router) it says "By returning a promise for the list of heroes from `$routerOnActivate()` we can delay the activation of the Route until the heroes have arrived successfully. This is similar to how a `resolve` works in `ngRoute`." but it does not seem to be blocking until the promise returns.