# Angular 1.5.x Component Router Resolve (2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-component-router, angular-components

How can I make a component route wait for a data befere to execute the controller and render the view. Similar to `resolve` of `ngRoute` and `ui-router`.

The documentation has this:

[image: Angular Component Router]

This only wait for the url change, ex:

```
//Old url
http://localhost/#/

// wait the promise (eg 1s) and then change the url to
http://localhost/#/heroes
```

But the view was changed immediately after the click in link, and then the url was changed, so weird!

This don't block the view render or controller execution (obviously).

> Demo of this situation:
>
> Code and preview: [plunkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/WYbqWgb0BUmMoWzxZNx7?p=preview) **(click in heroes)**

There are a similiar question that has no answers: [Angular 1.5.x Component Router Resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266340/angular-1-5-x-component-router-resolve)

Answer (score 2):

#### I found a solution:

This should be configured in the component definition:

```
.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: './my-compnent.html',
    controller: MyComponentCtrl,
    $canActivate: function($nextInstruction, $prevInstruction) {
      return Promise.resolve(<true or false>);
    }
})
```